# Falla en carga de datos en DDL ASP.NET MVC y JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, mvc

tengo una aplicacion asp.net mvc. También uso jquery para hacer las llamadas a las acciones que llenan los dropdownlist y otros objetos.
Cuando se publica el aplicativo en un servidor con IIS los dropdownlist no se llenan y al inspeccionar el código presenta recurso no encontrado (404 not found).
lugo de muchas pruebas note que la ruta que sale del IIS es algo así como https://sitio/controlador pero para que se carguen los ddl se utilizaría https://sitio/controlador/controlador .
Mi pregunta es cómo podría lograr que las rutas en el jquery funcionen sin tener que agregar el nombre del controlador dos veces a la ruta. Gracias por la ayuda.

```
//Accion en controller
public async Task<ActionResult> dtSourceDdlClasificacion(string term = "")
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var TipoFuente = clasificacionService.GetListByNombreActivos(term).ToList();
        List<classSelect2> items = new List<classSelect2>();
        foreach (var item in TipoFuente)
        {
            classSelect2 dt = new classSelect2();
            dt.id = item.idCLASIFACTIVIDAD.ToString();
            dt.text = item.cadDESCRIPCION;
            items.Add(dt);
        }
        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    });
}
    
    
//JQuery
function DdlClasificacion() {
    $("#idCLASIFACTIVIDAD").select2({
        placeholder: "Seleccione",
        language: "es",
        allowClear: true,
        ajax: {
            url: 'Divulgacion/dtSourceDdlClasificacion',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            quietMillis: 50,
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    term: term.term,
                };
            },
            processResults: function (items) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(items, function (item) {

                        return {
                            text: item.text,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    })
                };
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Agrega el controlador completo y el program.cs